# Necessary and/or sufficient conditions for $A+B$ to be invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ real invertible matrices. Are there necessary and/or sufficient conditions (involving only $A$ and $B$ separately, not $(A+B)$ iteself) for $A+B$ to be invertible? We exclude, for example, the trivial conditions $\text{det}(A+B)\neq 0$ and $\text{det}((A+B)^T)\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, $\det(A+B)\neq 0$, but I guess you want something else? Maybe you can be more specific?

Comment: Yep! I'll edit the question.

Comment: Any such conditions will be equivalent to $\det(A+B)\neq 0$.  It is possible that two invertible matices add to be noninvertible.  It is possible that two invertible matrices add to be invertible.  Similarly it is possible that two noninvertible matrices add to be either noninvertible or invertible.  The linear dependence or independence tells us nothing either.  One could discuss eigenvectors and require that $A$ and $B$ do not share an eigenvector but have opposite eigenvalues associated with that eigenvector, but that need not occur.

Comment: You might like [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690437) from Mathematics Magazine, written by Kenneth S. Miller.

Comment: There won't be any meaningful "separate" necessary conditions. If there is one such condition about $A$ that doesn't involve $B$ and it's meaningful, then there must be an exceptional case $A_0$ that violates this condition (a condition that is satisfied by every $A$ is by no means meaningful), but then the pair $(A,B)=(A_0,I-A_0)$ would make $A+B$ invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sufficient condition: If $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, $A+B$ is positive definite and therefore invertible. Also if $A$ is positive semi-definite and $B$ is positive definite, $A+B$ is positive definite and invertible.

Comment: where does the concept you have mentioned of "positive definite" discussed? I have taken a undergraduate course in LA, and in Lay's books there was nothing like this mentioned.

Comment: I apologize, but it has been a long time since I opened a LA book, and I'm not familiar with the one you mentioned. I would think that positive definiteness is typically be covered in introductory LA texts. If you can't find a good book, there's a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) on this topic.

Comment: thank you, I didn't think I'd be replied. But, your hint helps.... :-)

Answer (score -2):

No, because two invertible matrices A and B, when added, may end up non-invertible.

Comment: You mean $(A+B)^T$ is invertible? Also, I am interested in conditions on only $A$ and $B$ separately, not conditions on $(A+B)$ itself.